# Handling multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 6 arrays named , x1,......x6 that i read from 'npz' file. I need to perform some mathematical job on each array and stored that into 10 new arrays. I am doing it step by step in a very simple way. To read the file and store variables,

```
files = np.load("particle.npz")
x1 =  files['x1']
x2 = files ['x2']
x3 =  files['x3']
x4 = files ['x4']
x5 =  files['x5']
x6 = files ['x6']
```

create another array from previous one,

```
pox1= x1[:,0]
pox2= x2[:,0]
pox3= x3[:,0]
pox4= x4[:,0]
pox5= x5[:,0]
pox6= x6[:,0]
```

Then create some new arrays,

```
sq_diff_x1 = np.zeros(40002) 
sq_diff_x2 = np.zeros(40002)
sq_diff_x3 = np.zeros(40002)
sq_diff_x4 = np.zeros(40002)
sq_diff_x5 = np.zeros(40002)
sq_diff_x6 = np.zeros(40002)
```

And lastly perform calculation using for loop and store into new arrays,

```
for i in range (len(x1)-1):
    sq_diff_x1[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
    sq_diff_x2[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
    sq_diff_x3[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
    sq_diff_x4[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
    sq_diff_x5[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
    sq_diff_x6[i] = (pox1[i]-pox1[0])**2
```

The code is working fine but is there any other way where I can do it automatically by not assigning everything one by one? Because using my method is simple but will be very time consuming when I need work with 100 arrays.So something automated things are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = np.load("particle.npz")
x_s = [files[key] for key in files.keys()]
```

Creating a list of arrays rather than individually named ones is the preferred method in Python.

```
pox_s = [x[:,0] for x in x_s]
```

Looks like the arrays are all the same size.  So we can turn the list into an array:

```
pox_s = np.array(pox_s)
```

Or even

```
x_s = np.array(x_s)           # (6, 40002, ?)
pox_s = x_s[:,:,0]            # (6, 40002)

sq_diffs = (pox_s - pox_s[:,[0]])**2     # (6, 40002)-(6,1)
```

Without a small concrete example, I can't test this code.  I think I've got the shapes right.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to write an extra loop to iterate over the keys of the dictionary.

```
files = np.load("particle.npz")
sq_diff_list = []
temp = []
for i in list(files.keys()):
  arr = files[i]
  for x in arr:
    temp.append((x-arr[0])**2)
  sq_diff_list.append(temp)
  temp = []
```

Comment: "particle.npz" gives you a [dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/). When you do np.load, you load all files into the dictionary.
What do you mean by 'starting from loading files'?

Comment: like assigning variable x1,x2,..x6 automatically instead of one by one using this "x1 =  files['x1']"

Comment: Read my code carefully.
In my solution, I am not going over each 'x_i' separately. The first for loop does that. If you follow my code, sq_diff_list[i] in my code is same as sq_diff_xi from your code.